# Save .html file with COM "InternetExplorer.Application" object

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer, com

I try to get this page's HTML code(http://www.google.com/search?tbs=simg:CAESEgmbKK4nJ8pyZiGCp1jyKj6SXg&tbm=isch),
but `file_get_contents($url);` can't work on this page.

So I think using InternetExplorer.Application is a way,
I find a php script about website screenshots:

```
<?php $Browser = new COM('InternetExplorer.Application');
$Browserhandle = $Browser->HWND; $Browser->Visible = true;
$Browser->Fullscreen = true;
$Browser->Navigate('http://www.google.com/search?tbs=simg:CAESEgmbKK4nJ8pyZiGCp1jyKj6SXg&tbm=isch');

while($Browser->Busy){   com_message_pump(4000); }

$img = imagegrabwindow($Browserhandle, 0); $Browser->Quit();
imagepng($img, 'screenshot.png'); ?>
```

BUT **how can I save a .html file or get HTML code with "InternetExplorer.Application"?**

poor English, sorry, Thank you.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. So far as I can tell (MS docs can be hard to find) [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms970456.aspx) details everything you can do with `InternetExplorer.Application`, and saving anything, let alone the currently rendered DOM, doesn't seem to be available. Another point though - Google make it intentionally difficult to scrape their pages like this, and doing so is a violation of their ToS - why do you want to do this? What is the end goal here?

Comment: If `file_get_contents` doesn't work, have you considered doing a lower level cURL request? It allows much more control over how the request is handled and will probably work fine. http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: Thank you for the nice comment, I try to get some similar images results, but I can't find a way to use Google API to do this. I don't know it is a violation of the ToS, but I just a student and use it in education.

Comment: @cillosis I tried, but still can't work on this page. Maybe my php coding level is too poor, can you give me a example? thank you!